# Transferring ERC721 tokens with web3j using an operator

Tags: tokens, nft, web3j, transfer

I've been struggling using web3j (the web 3 Java library, not JS) transferring ERC721 tokens from one user to another, using an operator. I get that we need to approve the operator from the user that owns the token by using setApprovalForAll or approve methods. I have a few queries.

I really am confused on how, where and when to use these approve functions.

Do I need to call them from my web3j app, or can this all be done in solidity?

I would like to use safeTransferFrom which uses the receiver interface. From there, I would like to get the id of the token that was just transferred and get its URI. I can use the _transfer() method, but safeTransferFrom creates an error when I try and execute my transfer functions.

Here's my solidity code so far (btw all done in Remix)

approveOperator.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import 'https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol';
import 'https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/Counters.sol'
import "./example.sol";
import "./ERC721Received.sol";

contract apop is Example, received{

    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private tokIds;
     
     string tokenName = "";
     string tokenSymbol = "";
    
    constructor() Example(tokenName, tokenSymbol) public {

     }
    function ap(address operator, address owner) public{
      //   setApprovalForAll(op, true);
        IERC721(operator).setApprovalForAll(owner, true);
    }

    function mintToken(address _to, string memory _tokenURI)  public returns (uint256) {

       tokIds.increment()

      uint256 newTokenId = toUint256(response);
      //  _mint(_to, newTokenId);

      //   safeMint(_to, newTokenId);
      // setApprovalForAll(msg.sender, true);
         safeMint(msg.sender, tokIds.current());
         _setTokenURI(newTokenId, _tokenURI);
        
      return newTokenId;        
     }


    function tr(address from, address _to, uint256 tokenId, address opAddr) public payable{
      //   setApprovalForAll(_to, true);
         // _transfer(ownerOf(tokenId), _to, tokenId);
      IERC721(opAddr).transferFrom(from, _to, tokenId); // call operator's approve function from user's account
      //   safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, _to, tokenId);
     }
}
```

Here's my operator contract

```
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721Receiver.sol";
// import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "./example.sol";
import "./ERC721Received.sol";

 contract ExampleToken is Example, received {
     using Counters for Counters.Counter;
     Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;
     
     string tokenName = "";
     string tokenSymbol = "";
     uint256 tokenID1 = 0;

    
    constructor() Example(tokenName, tokenSymbol) public {

     }

    function mintToken(address _to, string memory _tokenURI)  public returns (uint256) {

       tokIds.increment()

      uint256 newTokenId = toUint256(response);
      //  _mint(_to, newTokenId);

      //   safeMint(_to, newTokenId);
      // setApprovalForAll(msg.sender, true);
         safeMint(msg.sender, tokIds.current());
         _setTokenURI(newTokenId, _tokenURI);
        
      contractAddress.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("incrementCounter()"));
      return newTokenId;        
     }

     function returnaddress() public view returns(address){
        return address(this);
     }

     function ap(address op) public{
        setApprovalForAll(op, true);
    }

     function tr(address from, address _to, uint256 tokenId) public payable {
      //   setApprovalForAll(_to, true);
         // _transfer(ownerOf(tokenId), _to, tokenId);
        safeTransferFrom(from, _to, tokenId);
     }

 }
```

Happy to provide any more info, and thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
public  boolean mintNFTByAmountAndAddress(Web3j web3j, Credentials credentials, String contractAddress, int amount) {
        if (web3j == null) return false;
        if (credentials == null) return false;
        String methodName = "mint";
        String fromAddr = emptyAddress;
        Function function = new Function(
                methodName,
                Arrays.asList(new Address(credentials.getAddress()), new Uint256(amount)),
                Arrays.asList(new TypeReference<Type>() {
                }));

    String data = FunctionEncoder.encode(function);
    Transaction transaction = Transaction.createEthCallTransaction(fromAddr, contractAddress, data);

    EthCall ethCall;
    try {
        ethCall = web3j.ethCall(transaction, DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST).sendAsync().get();
        //List<Type> results = FunctionReturnDecoder.decode(ethCall.getValue(), function.getOutputParameters());
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;
}
```